# Git get file list in prepare-commit-msg hook

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit-hook, commit-message

I want to write a hook that prepares a commit message based on the paths of the changed files. Is it possible to get such a file list at that stage?

I checked the `githooks` manual entry, but it is kinda sparse.

Answer (score -1):

Use `git diff --cached --name-only -r` in the script